# CakePHP 4.5 / RHEL 9

Tags: php, cakephp, redhat, php-8.2, rhel9

I have installed a cakephp 4.5 on a Linux environment (so far no problem). The application works correctly. When I launch the project on a browser, I get the view that displays the state of cakephp (**PagesController.php**).

The problem is as follows:
When I create another controller and change the route (to see if I've reached my controller), it doesn't load and I get the "failed to open stream" error (not all the time).

I've set the rights to **root** or **apache** and **777** but it doesn't work. The only manipulation that works is the following:

- I move a file that already exists when installing cakephp, in my case **PagesController.php**, to another directory.
- I copy **PagesController.php** to **PagesController2.php**.
- I move **PagesController2.php** to its original directory, renaming it **PagesController.php**. The application still works.
- I then use the original **PagesController.php** file and duplicate it again as **PagesController2.php**.
- I move **PagesController2.php** to the Controller directory, renaming it **CityController.php** for example. I modify my route:
  `$builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'City', 'action' => 'index', 'home']);`

I have access to my page.

The problem is with all the files (css, js, img) I import into my project. The application having been developed locally.

If anyone has any ideas... Thank you.

I've looked at a lot of tutorials but no solution to my problem. I'm ready to try any solution that comes my way.

Comment: What does "change the route" mean? You shouldn't need to be doing any edits to routing for normal functionality. For example, if you have a CityController (should be "CitiesController" for maximal ease of use with Cake standards) with an index function, you should be able to visit `yoursite.com/city` and have it work.

Comment: Sounds like the Controller is not correlating with your City templates folder which is needed and based on your routing path, "index" action has to exist if you did just do the copy, paste and renaming of the file, the "index" function in your controller does not exist only the function "display". the "home" string is a pass param which only in this matter happens to be a template view based on the "display" function under the Pages/City Controllers. Renaming the function to index I believe would solve this.